# Delegate form UIView to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have UIView, what called Popup and poping from UIViewContorller(ParentVC)
On UIView I have 4 buttons. When buttons is pressed, it needs to open new Controllers from(ParentVC). I am using Delegate, were is my mistake?

```
//Popup.h
@protocol PopupDelegate
@required

- (IBAction)stepOfRestoration:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)clientCall:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)readyTo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)givePhone:(id)sender;

@end

@interface Popup : PSCustomViewFromXib

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <PopupDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view;

- (IBAction)stepOfRestoration:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)clientCall:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)readyTo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)givePhone:(id)sender;
```

In .m i have this:

```
@synthesize delegate;
....
- (IBAction)stepOfRestoration:(id)sender {
 [self.delegate buttonPressed];
}
```

And this is Parent .m

```
    ...
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,200,300);
    Popup *popup1 = [[Popup alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    popup1.delegate = self;
   ....

-(void)buttonPressed {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"infoSegue" sender:nil];
}
```

So were is my mistake?

Comment: `if ( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonPressed)] ){[delegate buttonPressed]; }` Put a likewise check and see if the control comes inside the if loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a method called `buttonPressed` in your protocol, you need to call a method in your protocol, e.g.

```
Popup.m
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
   [self.delegate stepOfRestoration:sender];
}

Parent.m
- (IBAction)stepOfRestoration:(id)sender {
   // some code
}
```

[Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/design-patterns-delegation--cms-23901) to long winded but hopefully helpful tutorial, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Parent .m`, you must conform all the methods which are defined in protocol. In your Parent.m file, `buttonPressed` method is not present in protocol. So update the name of below method with `buttonPressed` as follow:-

Update below code at `Popup.h` while declaring PopupDelegate methods

---

```
- (IBAction)stepOfRestoration:(id)sender;
```

With

---

```
-(void)buttonPressed;
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't add IBAction methods in your protocol

instead add following methods corresponding each button action

//Popup.h

```
@protocol PopupDelegate
@required

- (Void)stepOfRestoration:(id)sender;
- (Void)clientCall:(id)sender;
- (Void)readyTo:(id)sender;
- (Void)givePhone:(id)sender;

@end
```

and call these protocol methods in corresponding button action methods

e.g. //Popup.m

```
- (IBAction)stepOfRestoration:(id)sender {
 [self.delegate stepOfRestoration:sender];
}
```

and  //Parent.m

```
-(Void)stepOfRestoration:(id)sender{
// code here
}
```